# C920 webcam h264 hardware encoder setting

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, h.264

I have webcam C920 that can output h264  （constrained baseline）.

I want to stream this C920s h264 video to browser.

I use h264_live_player for streaming video.
h264_live_player is javascript library for h264 streaming to browser, but it can only decode baseline profile.
so I want to know how to change C920s output h264 profile.

if i can't change C920s output profile, please tell me how to streaming to browser from C920 no reencoding.

Answer (score 0):

Try using motion. [Look at this tutorial.](https://learnraspi.com/raspberry-pi-webcam-stream-server-tutorial-live-streaming/) If you do not need to stream to a web  browser then VLC will also work and VLC is also cross platform. [Look at this thread for instructions to use VLC.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4412/streaming-h264-with-logitech-c920)